# Problema com KEY do Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou com um problema em colocar o mapa do Google Maps em meu site.
Já gerei uma KEY no painel e peguei o exemplo mais simples do Google e não está dando certo.

O erro apresentado é:

> "Ops! Algo deu errado. Esta página não carregou o Google Maps
>   corretamente. Consulte o console JavaScript para ver detalhes
>   técnicos."

O que normalmente acontece devido à Key. Porém já gerei DIVERSAS e nada.

Alguém já teve esse problema?

Eu usei o exemplo do Google mesmo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEYAQUI&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Eu coloquei minha key certinho, ali onde tem KEYAQUI no script

Obrigada

Comment: Ha boa, ainda bem. Vamos só apagar os cometários aqui para isso não ficar muito confuso

Comment: Precisa associar sua API com uma conta de faturamento. Para isso você precisará de um cartão de crédito válido.

Answer (score 3):

1. Painel do Crome, disponível em: `https://console.developers.google.com >
   Bibliotecas >`
2. Procure pela API: Google Maps JavaScript API
3. Ative a API